# How to parse python input file

Tags: python, file, csv, parsing, input

I have a file with tab separated values such as:

```
"1" "12345" "abc" "def"
"2" "67890" "abc" "ghi"
"3" "13578" "jkl" "mno"
```

I can't figure out how to take arbitrary numbers from an input file and, if the first 5 digits match what is in the second column of the input file, then every thing on that line will be exported into another file.

Ex: input file: "67890123"

```
output file: "2"   "67890"   "abc"   "ghi"
```

Comment: What's your code so far and where is it not working.

Comment: how big is the first file? I would suggest reading each line into a dictionary where the 5 digit number is the key: `{"12345": ("1", "12345", "abc", "def"), "67890": ("2", "67890", ...)...}` then simply index into the dictionary with the first 5 digits of the input.

Comment: This is a basic problem that python and you can handle very easily.
read the file line by line
split the line, creating a list
if condition true:
---- store the required data into a data structure
When done reading, write the data structure to a file
This example may help:
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/Files/Iteratingoverlinesinafile.html

Comment: The input file is 11 MB and contains over 150k lines. I'm not a Python programmer and don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: @ShawnSharp, Do you want to generate a single output file or as many output files as entries has the input file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` package to read and write your data file.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import pandas as pd

inputFileName = "D:/tmp/inputfile.txt"
dataFileName = "D:/tmp/data.csv"
outputFileName = "D:/tmp/outputfile.txt"

data = pd.read_csv(dataFileName, sep=' ', header=None)

with open(inputFileName) as f:
    input = f.readlines()
input = [int(x[0:5]) for x in input]

output = pd.DataFrame()
for value in input:
    output = output.append(data[data[data.columns[1]] == value])

output.to_csv(outputFileName, sep=' ', header=None, index=False)
```

So if your input file has

```
67890123
13578010
```

And your data is

```
"1" "12345" "abc" "def"
"2" "67890" "abc" "ghi"
"3" "13578" "jkl" "mno"
```

The output file would be:

```
2 67890 abc ghi
3 13578 jkl mno
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', required = True)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open('input.txt') as file:
    entries = file.readlines()
    ## Do not remove new line character at end as it will be useful to print new lines.

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for entry in entries:
        components = entry.split('\t')
        if components[1][1: 6] == args.input[:5]:
            # Note indexing of slicing starts from 1 to 6. Reason for that is there is 
            # explicit quote symbol present in input. 
            file.write(entry)
```

To run this code:
`> python my_file.py --input='67890'`

The code is self explanatory, let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

E2A: Multiple inputs..

Assuming you have loaded the input from a tsv file

You use simple boolean comparison

the simple Python way is:

```
import csv
input = ['67890231', '12345065']


with open("so.tsv") as tsv:
    for line in csv.reader(tsv, dialect="excel-tab"):
        for item in line:
            match = [line for x in line if x == item[:5]]

        print(match)
```

returns:

```
[['1', '12345', 'abc']]
[['2', '67890', 'def']]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import os, re
import argparse as ap

p = ap.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-i', '--input', required = True)
args = p.parse_args()

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for value in f.read().split('\n'):
        if str(re.split(r'\s+',value)[1]).replace('"', '') == args.input[:5]:
            open('output.txt', 'w').write(value)
```